# WebGL: How can blend each draw with the previous framebuffer with custom blending modes?

Tags: webgl, blending

I am implementing a brush engine using webgl. For each stamp i draw, i want to this stamp blend with the previous drawing in the framebuffer, with my own custom blending function to achive some cool effects. I know I can draw the stamp to a custom texture and blend the custom texture with the previous drawing framebuffer using shaders. But since the canvas is very big, so the performance is very slow as there are lots of stamps to draw.

I know in OpenGL ES2.0, apple provide a EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch extension for doing this, and it is fast. But how can do this in WebGL with better performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fetch from the destination framebuffer in WebGL yet, even with extensions.

You'll need to ping-pong between two different texture-backed framebuffers, sampling from one while drawing into the other. (can draw more than once per frame here if desired, in response to mouse events!) Then just draw the most-recently-drawn-framebuffer's texture to the backbuffer every frame in requestAnimationFrame.